# In react, insert response array into setState

Tags: reactjs, axios

```
class Search extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      searchResult: {
        "sr": []
      }
    }

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    this.setState = this.setState.bind(this)

  }

  onSubmit = formProps => {
    console.log(formProps.searchItem);
    cryptoSearch.searchNames(formProps.searchItem)
      .then((names) =>
        console.log(names),
        this.setState({
          sr: { names }
        }),
        console.log(this.state.sr)
      ) // [ 'BTC Lite', 'BTCMoon' ]
      .catch(err => console.log(err))

  };


  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ errorMessage: '' });
  }
```

I want to use onsubmit function to display the search result from an api. I declared an array called sr in constructor, and onSubmit function, when I use a package(similar to axios) to get a names(response) array object, how can I insert the names array into sr array??

Comment: For the sake of clarity you are getting a `names` array from your `cryptoSearch.searchNames` right?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set in state while I am assuming `names` from the response is an array.

```
this.setState({
   sr: names
 },()=>{ console.log(this.state.sr);});
```

You can then verify in callback of `setState` as setState is an asynchronous type.

Answer (score 0):

If `names` is an array and you want to update your `sr` property with this array you can use ES6 spread operator and set your state like that:

```
this.setState(prevState => ( {
        searchResult: { ...prevState.searchResult, sr: names }
    } )
);
```

If you set your state directly with `sr` like in your code you will loose other properties of `searchResult` and your state shape will change also something like this:

```
this.state = {
     "sr": []
}
```

One other point is since setState is asynchronous if you console.log your state immediately after setting your state, you can't get healthy results. Instead use a callback for this:

```
this.setState(prevState => ( {
            searchResult: { ...prevState.searchResult, sr: names }
        } ), () => console.log(this.state.searchResult.sr)
    );
```

or do not bother logging here with a callback and do it in your render method for logging purposes:

```
render(){
    console.log(this.state.searchResult.sr);
    return( .... )
}
```

Comment: I have to use sr: {names}, otherwise, it will indicate 'names' is not defined  no-undef; names always return an array like this : ["BTC Lite", "BTCMoon"]

Comment: How so? If you use `{names}` this means you are setting an object to `sr` field including `names` here, not an array. `names` can't be undefined since your are getting it in your `.then` method.

Answer (score 0):

If `names` is an array then you can set it to state as

```
onSubmit = formProps => {
console.log(formProps.searchItem);
cryptoSearch.searchNames(formProps.searchItem)
  .then((names) =>
    this.setState({
      sr: names 
    }),
  ) 
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

};